# Rails delayed_job start and stop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm using delayed_job on my project, and until now calling rake jobs:work in the console it worked.

But now I'm trying to stop the processing of jobs after a concret event, and continue processing after other event.

To simulate this behaviour I've created a script config/initializers/delayed_jobs.rb

```
puts "START DELAYED JOB PRE"
`script/delayed_job start`
puts "START DELAYED JOB POST"
```

And only the first puts is called, the server has mired in the instruction, and the web is not  being showed.

How to call stop and start delayed_jobs getting the correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can move it into an own thread:

```
puts "START DELAYED JOB PRE"
Thread.new do
    `script/delayed_job start`
end
puts "START DELAYED JOB POST"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using external daemon that would be responsible for keeping your workers up. I had quite good experience with `resque-pool` that is designed for `resque` queue. Usually such daemon would allow you pausing workers just by sending signal to a master process. It also makes deployment restarts and management quite easy.